# Let $p$ be prime. If an INFINITE group has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, why can't the group be cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be prime.  If a group has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, why can't the group be cyclic?

I understand how to prove this if the group is **finite** because the contrapositive of this statement is true due to the Euler-$\phi$ function $\phi (p) = p - 1$, which is the number of elements of order $p$.

But how would I prove this for **infinite** groups?

Comment: Are you aware that there is only one infinite cyclic group?

Comment: I am unaware of that.  I can see that $\langle 1 \rangle$ and $\langle -1 \rangle$ generate $\Bbb Z$, and $\langle k \rangle$ and $\langle -k \rangle$ generate $k \Bbb Z$, but I haven't proven that there are no other infinite cyclic groups.

Comment: Given any infinite cyclic group $\langle g \rangle$, you get an isomorphism by mapping $g$ to $1\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only element of finite order in an infinite cyclic group is the neutral element, which has order $1$. (If you do not know this, prove it.) Thus, for an infinite cyclic group there are never more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$ for $p$ a prime; indeed there never exists an element of order $p$.